# Eclipse Neon + JBossTools + Maven results on error: No compiler is provided in this environment

Tags: eclipse, maven, wildfly

I'm having some problems when trying to install `wildfly.swarm` addon (https://github.com/forge/wildfly-swarm-addon) through `JBoss Tools` on `Eclipse`

`Maven` keep telling me that java compiler was not found despite I have JDK correctly set on Eclipse.

But ok, first things first:

I installed `Java 8` + `Maven v3.3.9` + `Eclipse Neon` + `JBoss Tools`. Everything went fine...
Then, I tried to install `wildfly.swarm` addon (https://github.com/forge/wildfly-swarm-addon) through `JBoss Tools`.

`Forged Console` prompted me the following error:

[image]

Trying to solve this problem, I checked if JDK path is correct on Eclipse. It is:

[image]
I've also checked if system variables for Maven and Java home are correct. Also, everything seems fine:

[image]

At last, I went to `Windows > Preferences > Maven > Installations` on `Eclipse`
and added a new entry that point's to current Maven directory:

[image]

I've been looking some solutions on Stackoverflow and, between some sugestions, someone told to add tools.jar on `JRE Definition`. So, I did it, then restarted Eclipse, tried again to install `wildfly-swarm` through `Forge Console` but again... same error.

[image]

Did someone faced this problem as well?

Plus: I also tried to build Widlfly Swarm's example through `mv package` command and everything went fine:

[image]

Comment: You have a jre in your PATH variable, that's why Java --Versions Shows you a jre and that will be used by maven

Comment: Hey Jens! Thanks in advance for your quick response.

The Path variable is pointing to JDK's home's directory, that's for sure.
And I tried to build Wildfly Swarm's example using `mvn package` command and everything went fine. I edited my response in order to give so more info on this

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same problem. I can run mvn install on command line, but not in eclipse. You can temporarily fix this problem by adding this in pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javac.exe</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```